# Conditional recoding of factor to factor

Tags: r, tidyverse, recode, tibble

I have a tibble, `df`, with a factor, `A`, I wish to:

1) copy of,`C`, and
2) recode based on a second variable, `B`.

At the moment I'm doing it in this roundabout way. I'm quite confused by the conditional recoding of factor. I also looked at [`dplyr`'s `recode`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/recode.html), but couldn't work out a smarter method.

```
library(tibble)
df  <- tibble(
  A = factor(c(NA, "b", "c")), 
  B = c(1,NA,3)
)
```

My initial tibble

```
df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>        A     B
#>   <fctr> <dbl>
#> 1   <NA>     1
#> 2      b    NA
#> 3      c     3
```

Step #1 in my current solution

```
df$C <- with(df, ifelse(is.na(B), 'B is NA', A)) 
df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>        A     B       C
#>   <fctr> <dbl>   <chr>
#> 1   <NA>     1    <NA>
#> 2      b    NA B is NA
#> 3      c     3       2
```

Step #2 in my current solution

```
df$C <- dplyr::recode_factor(df$C, '2' = 'c')
df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>        A     B       C
#>   <fctr> <dbl>  <fctr>
#> 1   <NA>     1    <NA>
#> 2      b    NA B is NA
#> 3      c     3       c
```

How am I suppose to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `dplyr::if_else`, convert factor to character, then convert to factor again:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(C = factor(if_else(is.na(B), "B is NA", as.character(A))))

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#          A     B       C
#     <fctr> <dbl>  <fctr>
#   1   <NA>     1    <NA>
#   2      b    NA B is NA
#   3      c     3       c
```

Comment: Thanks. It answers my question, I'm however still surprised by what to me seems as first going to one pace and then going back, i.e. _convert factor to character, then convert to factor again_.

Comment: @EricFail if we didn't need to say "B is NA" we could just do: `df$C <- df$A; df$C <- ifelse(is.na(df$B), NA, df$C)`

Answer (score 1):

The conversion is happening in `ifelse`. From the docs:

> **Value**
>
> A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and
>   `"class"`) as `test` and data values from the values of `yes` or `no`. The
>   mode of the answer will be coerced from logical to accommodate first
>   any values taken from `yes` and then any values taken from `no`.

Because `yes` is `"B is NA"`, which is a character vector, the output is a character vector. That the values from `A` are converted to integer and then converted to character is a weird implementation outcome. Factors are really integer vectors with modified `class` and `levels` attributes.

You could also achieve this by copying A, adding `"B is NA"` to the acceptable levels, and then replacing a subset.

```
df$C <- df$A
levels(df$C) <- c(levels(df$C), "B is NA")
df$C[is.na(df$B)] <- "B is NA"
df
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#        A     B       C
#   <fctr> <dbl>  <fctr>
# 1   <NA>     1    <NA>
# 2      b    NA B is NA
# 3      c     3       c
```

Note that if you don't add `"B is NA"` to the levels, all the replaced values will be `NA` with a warning. Factors are restricted to only take specific values. If you want to add a new one, you have to explicitly do so.